# Backbone js routing on page load/refresh without hash

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this in my router

```
# ROUTING
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend(

  routes:
    '': 'homePage'
    'photography': 'photographyPage'
    'about': 'aboutPage'
    'contant': 'contantPage'

  initialize: ->
    that = this
    @route 'photography', 'photographyPage', ->
      that.photographyPage()

    pageWrapper = $('#pageWrapper')
    content = $('#content')

  homePage: ->
    console.log 'homepage'

  photographyPage: ->
    console.log 'photography'
)
```

After I initiate the router

```
new (App.Router)
Backbone.history.start 
 pushState: true
```

In my html I have this

```
<nav>
  <a href="/photography" class="inbound-link">Photography</a>
  <a href="/about" class="inbound-link">About</a>
  <a href="/contact" class="inbound-link">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

I am able to navigate to the above links just fine. But I'm running into a problem where if I land at `http://website.com/photography` and refresh the page I get 404 not found. Or if i go directly to that url I get 404 as well. I tried this route `http://website.com/#/photography` and that worked however when it loaded it, it stripped out the `#` and replaced it with `http://website.com/photography`

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any direct link e.g example.com/photography will lead to the server trying to evaluate it without ever hitting your backbone app on the index page. Backbone goes around this by using hash paths i.e: `example.com#/photography`. Unless your backbone is on the server, you have to rely on hash paths for backbone to evaluate them successfully.

Comment: check this link out.. if this article can help you... http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `href="/#photography"` ?

hope it helps

Comment: I was hoping to keep clean urls without the hashes, but for now I can go with this route

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're requesting the path `/photography` from your HTTP server, and it's not finding the right file.

You'll need to configure your server to serve your html file for any (or certain) paths that might be requested.

The right way to do that will vary depending on your server (apache, nginx, etc)